# Sencha Touch, Apigee JS SDK, and Phonegap working in browser but not IOS

Tags: javascript, api, sencha-touch, apigee

Using - Sencha Touch 2.3, Apigee Usergrid JS SDK, and PhoneGap 3.2.

I am able to run my app in the browser and access Apigee perfectly.

index.html:

```
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../lib/apigee.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true </script>
<!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Command to build your application -->
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src=".sencha/app/microloader/development.js"></script>`
```

This is my code straight from Apigee Javascript SDK(again in index.html):

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
     var client = new Usergrid.Client({
         orgName:'orgname',
         appName:'sandbox',
         logging: true, 
         buildCurl: true
        });
</script>`
```

So to test in my view "client.URI" gives me "https://api.usergrid.com" as expected.  All good  there.

Image here of "client.URI" in a button.
http://minus.com/i/BtmXiuVxljsV

When I run

```
$ sencha app build -run native
```

This is where I run into problems.  Everything works great except when I try to tie in Apigee.  The app does not load in the IOS emulator when I do.  In my phonegap config or "whitelist" I have opened up access to everything with the "*" wildcard.  I am pretty sure this is working because Google maps API is working great.  I tried to put the "client.URI" test in an alert so when I click a button it shows me the URI.  Again this works in the browser, but not in the emulator.  The app loads fine but when I click on the button nothing happens.  I hope this makes sense.  I wanted to make sure the app would load and that I could test the "client.URI" test as independently as possible.  Again if I try to render it on load then the app never even loads in the emulator.

When I click on the button that should have an alert with the URI I get this in the system.log:

```
` <Error>: __hid_dispatch_pthread_root_queue_create_block_invoke: specific=0x505c260 pthread_self=0xb0115000`
```

I could keep developing in the browser and have access to my Usergrid backend, but I would really like to get this bug fixed and make sure I am not dealing with a bigger architectural problem.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: what version of ios are you emulating in the ios emulator?

Comment: Tried it again with 6 and got the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally! Thank goodness for nice debugging help from Android.  I changed routes and tried it with Android.

It was telling me it couldn't find the Apigee.min.js file.  Seems when Phonegap was compiling it either put it in the wrong place or I did to begin with(I'm pretty sure I know which it was)

I changed out my local file to this instead:

```
 <script src="https://apigee.com/usergrid/sdk/usergrid.0.10.5.js"></script>
```

and it works now on IOS and Android.  Was very strange because it worked so well in the browser previously.

If anyone has some feedback on where I went wrong with the putting the file in my app let me know.  As you can see above it was in:

```
<script src="../lib/apigee.min.js"></script>
```

Also if anyone has recommendations on when deploying if I should keep using Apigee as a source or adding the file to my app.

Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that may make a difference is trying to run the emulator from XCode instead of from the command line.  Open the .xcodeproj file that Phonegap makes and run from there.  If the emulator still doesn't launch, please let us know.

Comment: So I ran the xcodeproj file as you mentioned and am getting the same results.  I did use the phonegap command line to create the .xcodeproj file though.  Once this was complete I opened in xcode and ran the emulator.  Again, same outcome.  Just to clarify the emulator does launch with the command line tool as well as long as I do not make any calls to the Usergrid API.  I put one in an alert on a button tap event and this is not rendering.  So it seems to be something specific to the interaction with Usergrid.